# Wireshark C dissector error when filling subtree

Tags: c, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a simple Wireshark dissector which throws the following bug warning when it is run against a capture:

```
13:04:12          Warn Dissector bug, protocol usbserial, in packet 353: /wireshark/epan/proto.c:5504: 
failed assertion "idx >= 0 && idx < num_tree_types"
```

The protocol registration function looks like this:

```
static gint ett_myproto = -1;

void 
proto_register_myproto(void)
{
    /* Set up field array */
    static hf_register_info hf[] = {
        { &hf_myproto_payload,
            {"Payload", "myproto.payload", FT_BYTES, BASE_NONE, NULL,
                0x0, NULL, HFILL }},
    };

    /* Register protocol */
    proto_myproto = proto_register_protocol("My Protocol", "myproto", "myproto");
    /* Register protocol fields */
    proto_register_field_array(proto_myproto, hf, array_length(hf));

    /* Register the dissector */
    register_dissector("myproto", dissect_myproto, proto_myproto);
}
```

The dissector does some general munging of data, but the core of the problem area seems to be:

```
static int
dissect_myproto(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree,
        void *data _U_)
{
    proto_item *ti;
    proto_tree *myproto_tree;

    /* Create top tree and add to the item */
    ti = proto_tree_add_protocol_format(tree, proto_myproto, tvb, 0, -1,
            "My Protocol");
    myproto_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(ti, ett_myproto);

    proto_tree_add_bytes_format(myproto_tree, hf_myproto_payload,
            tvb, 0, payload_len,
            NULL, "Payload");
}
```

What do I need to do to get the protocol to fill the subtree correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is a failure to register the subtree as part of a subtree array (hint from [here](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/200807/msg00258.html)).

This is done in the protocol registration function, and requires "packaging" the subtree variables (of which there is only one here: `ett_myproto`) into an array, and then registering that array using `proto_register_subtree_array`:

```
static gint ett_myproto = -1;

void 
proto_register_myproto(void)
{
    /* Set up field array */
    static hf_register_info hf[] = {
        ....
    };

    /* Register protocol */
    proto_myproto = proto_register_protocol("My Protocol", "myproto", "myproto");
    /* Register protocol fields */
    proto_register_field_array(proto_myproto, hf, array_length(hf));

    /* Setup and register all protocol subtrees */
    static gint *ett[] = {
        &ett_myproto,
    };

    proto_register_subtree_array(ett, array_length(ett));

    /* Register the dissector */
    register_dissector("myproto", dissect_myproto, proto_myproto);
}
```

The `ett` variables are indices used to refer to GUI information about the state of the subtree (e.g. expanded or not).

Comment: Generally such issues are easily caught when comparing against the sample dissector code at [doc/packet-PROTOABBREV.c](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/doc/packet-PROTOABBREV.c)